# Are Spring Data MongoDB connections thread bounded?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, tokumx

We are evaluating TokuMX so we could use its ACID transaction feature, but we want to use it with Spring Data for MongoDB.

So, here is the question: are MongoDB connections managed by Spring Data thread bounded so that we could take advantage of TokuMX transaction implementation?

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/#java-driver-concurrency

It looks like connections are pulled from an internal connection pool and returned "per request" <strike>so there is no database connection tied to a thread.</strike>

I haven't found a way to override this yet. Perhaps there is another driver out there, or a setting I haven't found yet.

Edit: Apparently I didn't read the article far enough. You should be able to use db.requestStart() to ensure the connection is keep for the thread.

There's a similar mention for C# and Python here:

http://docs.tokutek.com/tokumx/tokumx-transactions.html#tokumx-transactions-multi-statement-drivers